# Pandas MultiIndexing KeyError on partial label index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm trying to reproduce the "Basic indexing on axis with MultiIndex" portion of the pandas [user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html).

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)
print(df)
print(df['bar'])
```

I can't see why my code is any different from what is shown in the user guide. I have a KeyError: 'bar' in the last line.

Comment: `df.loc['bar']`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access `bar` you need to use `loc`, or transpose it, because `bar` is not in columns:

```
>>> df.loc['bar']
            0         1         2         3
one  0.888182  0.066730  1.397408 -0.550522
two -0.258916 -1.859689 -0.294348 -0.646791
```

transpose:

```
>>> df.T['bar']

        one       two
0  0.888182 -0.258916
1  0.066730 -1.859689
2  1.397408 -0.294348
3 -0.550522 -0.646791
```

**EDIT :**

As pointed out, very helpfully, in the comments, in case you want to keep the multiindex:

```
>>> df.xs('bar',drop_level=False)
                0         1         2         3
bar one -0.857271  1.271094  0.565691 -0.523375
    two  0.826911  0.244787  0.991158 -0.484815
```

Even though it will depend on your use-case, seems like you actually need:

```
>>> arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 8), columns=arrays)

>>> df

        bar                 baz                 foo                 qux          
        one       two       one       two       one       two       one       two
0  1.600817 -1.420187 -0.798078  1.632550 -0.737740 -1.036077 -1.034157  1.576907
1  0.111148 -1.830283  0.507195 -0.042425  0.260859 -1.600065 -0.449921  0.657582
2 -1.054305 -0.885309  0.325678 -0.253772 -0.444176  0.331933  0.332281  0.127738
3  1.071590  0.947280 -0.973616  0.677141  0.133742  1.352731 -0.210731  2.079073

# Then you can do either df['bar'] directly
```

References:

1. [`df.xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html)
2. [`df.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html)
3. [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)
4. The link in your question. I would suggest you to go through it thoroughly, it is very well explained.

Comment: Sure, I will add that, thanks. Still OP needs to either transpose or set the columns as multiindex.

Answer (score 0):

The part of the user guide you are referring to ([this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#basic-indexing-on-axis-with-multiindex)) is for when the dataframe's columns are multiindex. You should look at this [part](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index) for when the index is multiindex.

To access `bar`, you should do:

```
print(df.loc["bar"])
```